# IF my DB server goes down for some time, I have to reset IIS every time to re-establish the connection

Tags: .net, iis, ado.net

IF my DB server goes down for some time, my app is not estarblishing the connection again.

I need to to manually reset the IIS /App pool to estrablish the connection again.

How to make my app to re-estrablish the connectin again on its own whoth out manual invervention.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, all I can suggest is altering your 'get connection' code to check the state of the connection, and try opening a new one if it's dead/invalid.